# How to de-select the Workstation only option on Novell Client 4.9 for Windows

Tags: novell

By default the checkbox is selected, I sometimes forget to de-select it when logging in, which then does not connect the workstation to the network. I would prefer to not have to de-select this checkbox each time logging into the workstation.

I have looked in these threads about changing registry entries, but no success.

[Controlling "Workstation Only" functionality during login](http://support.novell.com/docs/Tids/Solutions/10086294.html)

[Workstation Only checkbox always selected by default](http://forums.novell.com/novell-product-discussions/file-networking-services/open-enterprise-server/oes-platform-independent/oes-client-windows/379946-workstation-only-checkbox-always-selected-default.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your tool bar, the N icon, then Client Properties.  Probably can get there from Control Panels as well.

System Login Profiles: select Default from the list, then Properies.

Now I was sure, Workstation Only was a tick box here, but not on the Novell Client 2 SP1 I am running.  But there is a tick box, save profile after successful login, which means it should remember the last configuration you used.

Comment: I do not see / have a toolbar when the login form is open.  visible options are, besides the Workstation only checkbox (which we want un-checked) 4 buttons ok, cancel, shutdown and Advanced...  Clicking  Advanced button displays tabs eDirectory Script Windows Dial-up

Comment: @jamesTheProgrammer The "Save Profile after successful Login" is not on the login page, but rather in the settings, following the path I described.